# Scrollbar does not appear in linearlayout with multiples images

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm adding images to the layout via code like this:

```
linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
{
    image = new ImageView(this);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
    linear.addView(i);
}
```

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

</LinearLayout>
```

**My question is that the scroll bar is not showing up when I add more than 3 images.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Adding `LinearLayout` as parent layout, add linear layout inside ScrollView and add the child into the `LinearLayout`

Note:

> `ScrollView` should have only one immediate child

Answer (score 1):

Iam not see element scrollview in your codes
Try to add element scrollview.

for example :

Xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android_layout_width="fill_parent">

<ScrollView 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android_layout_width="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java :

```
linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
{
    image = new ImageView(this);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
    linear.addView(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this use `ScrollView`  as parent layout and make `LinearLayout`  child of  `ScrollView` and all controls in linear layout
like below layout

```
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">

  <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">
       // add here all your controls
 </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like all the other comments say, add a ScrollView as the root component of your layout.xml file.

Then, inside that ScrollView, add another LinearLayout tag and inside that add your items and components.
Just a reminder, only put the LinearLayout tag directly inside of the ScrollView, as a child. 
If you put more than one child inside a ScrollView tag, you will get an error.

```
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- Add your components, if they go beyond the screensize, the ScrollView will automatically generate a Scrollbar functionality for you-->

 </LinearLayout>

<!-- Don't put another component inside the ScrollView that isn't the LinearLayout-->

</ScrollView>
```